# How can I show a compose dialog multiple times in android?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In a legacy code project, inside a fragment, I need to show a compose dialog. This is how I display it

```
private fun showComposeDialog() {
        binding.composeView.setContent { TheDialog() }
}
```

And this is the dialog code:

```
@Composable
fun TheDialog() {
    val showDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    if (showDialog.value) {
        Dialog(onDismissRequest = { showDialog.value = false }) {
            // some content
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine the first time it's displayed. However, the second time the **showComposeDialog()** is called, the value of **showDialog** is false. I'm assuming this is because recomposition happens within the same ComposeView inside the fragment. If I create a new ComposeView in the fragment every time I want to display the dialog (and remove it after I set **showDialog** to false) this works without any issues.

I would like to avoid creating and removing the ComposeView every time. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Assuming only Dialog part is in compose, rest is xml: extract showDialog to outside, maybe in ViewModel and observe it in Fragment#observeComposeDialog. When it is true, call `setContent{Dialog()}`, when false call `setContent{}`

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov thanks, extracting showDialog into the fragment worked. clean, easy solution. if you put it down as an answer I'll mark it as the correct one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming only `Dialog` part is in Compose and rest is in XML:

Extract `showDialog` to outside, maybe into `ViewModel` and observe it in `Fragment#observeComposeDialog()`.

When `showDialog` is `true`, call `setContent{ Dialog() }`, and when `showDialog` is `false` call `setContent{}`